# Is it possible for a web service operation to return multiple types?

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wsdl

I'm working with a web service which is written by another team.

The operation which I'm using in the WSDL is:

```
<wsdl:operation name="transactionReport">
    <wsdl:input name="transactionReportRequest" message="schema:transactionReportRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="transactionReportResponse" message="schema:transactionReportResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

As it describes in WSDL the result of the `transactionReport` operation must be of type `transactionReportResponse`.

But in some cases (on error) it returns this XML as result:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header />
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <errorOccur xmlns="http://thecompany/servicesCompanyInfo/definitions">
      <errorCode>3</errorCode>
      <errorDescription>CUSTOMER_ID or FROM_DATE should have value</errorDescription>
    </errorOccur>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

It seems that it's against the WSDL. Am I true?

I expect this operation to return just `transactionReportResponse` or `Fault`.

**Question1:** Is it OK for this operation to return a `errorOccur` too?

**Question2:** If it's OK, then how can I get this object in C#? (As it returns null despite of the XML which contains a `errorOccur`)

Comment: an operation should not return a request, it should take one as parameter. it should return a response.
within that response, however, you can have:
- values
- a 'fault'
- ...

Comment: @Stultuske It was a type and I corrected it. Thanks